# How to trigger an event only when response is recieved from multiple APIs?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a component, where I need to call two APIs parallelly. And I want to call a method only when both the API calls are resolved.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceOne.someApi().subscribe((res) => {
        this.response1 = res;  
    });
    this.serviceTwo.someApi().subscribe((res) => {
        this.response2 = res;  
    });
}
```

I want to call a method only when `this.response1` and `this.response2` is getting populated.

Currently, I am wrapping the logic inside the method with an `if statement`.

```
someMethod() {
    if(this.response1 && this.response2) {
        //logic
    }
}
```

and putting `someMethod()` inside `subscribe()` of both the api calls.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **forkJoin** to achieve it.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cx6xez?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
  ngOnInit() {    
    const request1 = this.serviceOne.someApi();
    const request2 = tthis.serviceTwo.someApi();

    forkJoin([request1, request2]).subscribe(data => {
      this.response1 = data[0];
      this.response2 = data[1];
      this.someMethod();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does it wait if one API takes a longer time to resolve??

Comment: Yes. Read https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 0):

same answer with array destructuring.

```
forkJoin([
  this.serviceOne.someApi(),
  this.serviceTwo.someApi(),
]).subscribe(data => {
    let [serviceOneResponse, serviceTwoResponse] = data;
    // use responses.
});
```